# How to set custom node_modules path with typescript

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, node-modules, aws-lambda-layers

I'm starting to develop an AWS Lambda function in TypeScript. I want the `node_modules` directory to be on a subdirectory in order to be able to manage all dependencies in a layer. So I have the following strucutre :

```
- dependencies/            <- This will be my layer
  - nodesjs/
    - node_modules/
      ...
  - my_own_dependencies/
    ...
- src
  - blabla.ts
```

I use relative imports for `my_own_dependencies` and it works great.

But I can't get `tsc` to have node modules imported, whatever the module, I always get `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'xxxx'`. Using relative import doesn't really help either because if a module itself depends on another module, the error will still be thrown.

I've tried various combination of `compilerOptions` paramaters (`baseUrl`, `paths` and `rootDirs`) in `tsconfig.json` but none of them actually work.

Right now my tsconfig.json looks like this :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "commonjs"
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "dependencies/nodejs/node_modules"
      ]
    },
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Edit: Running `tsc --traceResolution blah/blah.ts` outputs the following:

```
Module resolution kind is not specified, using 'NodeJs'.
Loading module 'xxx' from 'node_modules' folder, target file type 'TypeScript'.
Directory '/path/to/blah/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
File '/path/to/node_modules/xxx.ts' does not exist.
...
And so on until:
Directory '/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
```

What's weird is that it says module resolution kind is undefined while it's clearly defined to "node" in `tsconfig.json`...

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, turned out `tsconfig.json` is ignored when specifying a specific source file to compile, probably I've missed that in the documentation... Everything is eventually fine when using Webpack or just runnning `tsc`.

I ended up having the following `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./dependencies/nodejs/node_modules",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "dependencies/nodejs/node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```